# After Effects Export as JPEG sequence results in huge file

Tags: compression, video-editing, video-encoding, adobe-after-effects

I have an After Effects project for school, and I've created a movie using JPEG sequences (10 @ ~100-200mb/each ). I have the output setting on the composition set to 640x480. I resized each JPEG layer via the fit to comp tool, but when I export the movie as a Quicktime movie, it is 1.1 gig for ~35 seconds of movie at 30fps.

What am I doing so horribly wrong here?

Comment: Are you exporting it as based on lostless? Those files no matter what format you use tend to be massive. I just rendered out one where the source files were 300 mb combined yet the final "lostless" render file was 4.3GB. I just opened quicktime pro and exported it again without changing settings. Came out to be around 400 mb. You just need to change the render settings most likely. Which after effects are you using?

Comment: @a sandwhich: The newest one as a Trial for OSX. It's for my 2D animation class, which is a supplement class, so I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Ah. CS5. I have worked with cs5 a little, but not much compared to cs4. I think the rendering is somewhat the same, so try rendering with diffrent output settings or just use an external program to reencode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your FPS and Compression settings, perhaps check if you can use another codec or format.